# Java enum with $ dollar sign not properly parsed with doxygen 1.8.13

Tags: java, enums, doxygen

Hi when I generate the htmldocumentation of an enum with a $ sign in its name, the html only contains the bit after the $ sign. Any ideas how to overcome this?

example:

```
public class SampleJava {

    /**
     * Sample Enum to show problems with $ sign and doxygen
     */
    public enum SampleEnum {
        /**
         * without dollar sign -> works
         */
        WITHOUT_DOLLAR,

        /**
         * with dollar sign -> does not work (i.e. html is $DOLLAR
         */
        WITH$DOLLAR
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you *really* need a dollar in the name? ["The $ sign should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8). Could you override the `toString()` method instead?

Comment: I do not _really_ need to use the $ sign, but it seemed quite handy for our naming conventions. And even if it should not been used, why does doxygen care.

Comment: @vowu You got a point, could be that doxygen does some text processing and treats $ as a special character. AFAIK, this character is used to include [LaTeX formulaes](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/formulas.html) but only after an escape char (backslash). So I'd file this as a bug.